# how to iterate over a dictionary from value in an array and store in a new dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, store, key-value

I have an array(Arr[]), for each item in the array i would like for it to go through a dictionary(specs{}) and calculate the corresponding values and store them in a new dictionary but on sure how to specify the key and value for this new dictionary {results{}).

```
Arr=["saucer", "shoes"]
def calc(Arr, context, user_results):
    results = {}
    for x in Arr:
        if x == specs.keys():
            results = specs.values
            results.append(x : results)
    return results

specs = {'cup': 3,'saucer': 5, 'bag': 17, 'shoes': 9}
```

results={"saucer": 5, "shoes": 9}

Comment: `results` is a dict. Assign key-value pair as : `results['some_key'] = some_value`

Comment: That is not an array, that is a *list*

Comment: yes my question was unclear, just moved the defined array into the code section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `dict` comprehension to build up a new `dict` using the items in `specs`

```
results = {key: specs[key] for key in Arr if key in specs}
```

Comment: I think you have `Arr` and `specs` mixed up: `Arr` is a list, and `specs` is the dictionary.

Comment: my defined array was not in the code section hence confusion. thanks for this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [9]: specs = {'cup': 3,'saucer': 5, 'bag': 17, 'shoes': 9}

In [10]: Arr=["saucer", "shoes"]

In [11]: R = {k: v for k, v in specs.items() if k in Arr}

In [12]: R
Out[12]: {'saucer': 5, 'shoes': 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input:**

```
Arr=["saucer", "shoes"]
specs = {'cup': 3,'saucer': 5, 'bag': 17, 'shoes': 9}
```

**Code #1:**

```
results = {item: specs.get(item, None) for item in Arr if item in specs}
```

**Code #2:**

```
results = {key: value for key, value in specs.items() if key in Arr}
```

**Result:**

```
{'saucer': 5, 'shoes': 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

just check the list and create another dictionary

```
specs = {'cup': 3,'saucer': 5, 'bag': 17, 'shoes': 9}

Arr= ["saucer", "shoes"]

em={}

for item in Arr:
    if item in specs:
        em[item] = specs[item]
print(em)

{'saucer': 5, 'shoes': 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `itemgetter` to get values from the dictionary and `zip` the `arr` list with the values to build a new dict:

```
from operator import itemgetter

arr = ["saucer", "shoes"]

specs = {'cup': 3, 'saucer': 5, 'bag': 17, 'shoes': 9}

dict(zip(arr, itemgetter(*arr)(specs)))
# {'saucer': 5, 'shoes': 9}
```